# I want to develop a background service in android which can notify the user whenever the camera app is launched

Tags: android, service

I want to develop a background service in android which can notify the user whenever the camera app is launched.This is my code to filter the recently running services. With the help of this code I am still not able to detect the current top activity of the stack which helps me find out if the specific application is launched.

**Service.java**

```
final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
final List<RunningTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
for (int i = 0; i < recentTasks.size(); i++) 
{
    if(recentTasks.get(i).topActivity.getPackageName().contains("camera") || recentTasks.get(i).topActivity.getPackageName().contains("Camera"))
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Camera open", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Hello, there are many issues with your post. I think you can fix them. 1) someone has already suggested an edit the post to help make it more readable. 2) You will need to expand upon that and ask a question. Because right now I don't actually see a 'question' we can help you with. You just make a statement that you want to make a service.

Comment: Write a broadcast receiver to get notified when camera app gets open.

Comment: @dhuma1981 I'm not aware (offhand) of an intent that gets launched by camera apps when they are opened. It could be possible to be notified when an intent hits the system to 'launch' a camera app, but I'm curious if there is something I'm not familiar with that you are referring to